# How can I select (target) first iframe?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to auto recognize which post contains iframe (video) and stick video to top of the post, while rest of the post (text with the title and other stuff) would be bellow it, because it looks nicer that way.

So far I have

```
/* If div with specific class has an iframe add another class to the div */
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.single-post:has(iframe)').addClass('video-post');
});
```

CSS:

```
.video-post .site-main .video-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.video-post .site-main .video-wrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.video-post .site-main {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 58.25% !important;
}
```

The problem is if the post has two videos, so how do I target only one (first) iframe with this modification while leaving other inside the post content?

Comment: If you position the video absolute what stops it overlaying other stuff so that can't be seen?

Comment: Padding top on .video-post .site-main